# R viewer pane is not showing D3 interactive graphs

Tags: r, d3.js, rstudio, bipartite

I am using bipartiteD3 package in latest version of R and R studio (downloaded yesterday).

When I run the sample commands and example files from `bipartite_D3` function package, it is not showing the interactive bipartite graph in viewer pane. Instead, an error message is appearing in the viewer pane mentioning that:

> d3.nest is not a function

I have attached a screenshot of the R studio page with the codes and the error.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Extremely sorry. I apologize for using non-recommended phrase / words. Actually, I have to present my Doctoral synopsis in our University next week. Hence, I mention this problem as "URGENT" as I need to be ready within 2-3 days with my presentation which will include the interactive graph mentioned above. I think the urgency will depend on the situation of the people who is facing the problem and the time he/she has within which the problem needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of d3 no longer includes functions included in the d3-collection module. It appears that r2D3 now uses this version (d3v6) by default, but bipartiteD3 still makes use of it. This means it can't access `d3.nest()`, which explains your error as `d3.nest` is no longer a method of d3.

BipartiteD3 could be updated relatively easily, but in the meantime there are a few options to correct this, for example, you could do one of:

1. install an older version of r2d3 to replace your current version

eg:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/r2d3/r2d3_0.2.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

or

2. edit the r package source files locally to pass the proper version to r2d3 (which is done with `d3_version = "5"`)

or

3. create a new function containing all the pieces of `bipartite_D3` but also pass a version parameter (also done with `d3_version = "5"`, essentially the same as #2, but without modifying the bipartiteD3 source)

eg:

```
library(r2d3)
library(bipartite )
library(purrr) 
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(bipartiteD3)


testdata <- data.frame(higher = c("bee1","bee1","bee1","bee2","bee1","bee3"), 
                       lower = c("plant1","plant2","plant1","plant2","plant3","plant4"), 
                       webID = c("meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow","meadow"), freq=c(5,9,1,2,3,7))
bipartite::frame2webs(testdata)-> SmallTestWeb

Used3v5<- function(data,
                        filename='bipartiteD3Script',
                        PrimaryLab = 'Primary',
                        SecondaryLab='Secondary',
                        SiteNames=NULL,
                        colouroption=c('monochrome', 'brewer', 'manual')[1],
                        HighlightLab = 'Unlinked',
                        HighlightCol = '#3366CC',
                        monoChromeCol = 'rgb(56,43,61)',
                        ColourBy = c(1, 2)[2],
                        BrewerPalette = 'Accent',
                        NamedColourVector,
                        MainFigSize = NULL,
                        SortPrimary=NULL,
                        SortSecondary=NULL,
                        mp = c(1,1),
                        MinWidth=10,
                        Pad=1,
                        IndivFigSize= c(200, 400),
                        BarSize = 35,
                        Orientation = c('vertical', 'horizontal')[1],
                        EdgeMode = c('straight','smooth' )[2],
                        BoxLabPos = NULL,
                        IncludePerc = TRUE,
                        PercentageDecimals =0,
                        PercPos = NULL,
                        CSS_Output_Supress = FALSE,
                        PRINT=FALSE){
  df<-NULL
  
  if(tibble::is_tibble(data)){
    data<- as.data.frame(data)
  }
  
  if(is.data.frame(data)){
    df<- data
  }else{
    if(is.list(data)){
      df<-List2DF(data, PrimaryLab,SecondaryLab,SiteNames)
    }else{
      dimensions<-length(dim(data))
      if(dimensions ==3){
        df<-Array2DF(data, PrimaryLab,SecondaryLab,SiteNames)
      }
      if(dimensions==2){
        df<-Matrix2DF(data,PrimaryLab,SecondaryLab, SiteNames)
      }
    }
  }
  if(is.null(df)){#
    stop('invalid data input. Valid forms are data frame, bipartite style matrix, list or array')
  }
  
  if((mp[2]*mp[1])> (ncol(df)-2)){
    warning('Making too many facets. Are you sure mp is set ok?')
  }
  if((mp[2]*mp[1])< (ncol(df)-2)){
    warning('Making too few facets. Guessing you want 1 row')
    mp[2]<-ncol(df)-2
  }
  
  if(is.null( MainFigSize)){
    MainFigSize<-c(mp[2]*700, mp[1]*700) # Having a reasonable guess at a default overall figure size
  }
  
  BP_JS_Writer(df = df,filename = filename,
               colouroption = colouroption,
               HighlightLab = HighlightLab,
               HighlightCol = HighlightCol,
               monoChromeCol = monoChromeCol,
               ColourBy = ColourBy,
               BrewerPalette = BrewerPalette,
               NamedColourVector = NamedColourVector,
               MainFigSize = MainFigSize ,
               SortPrimary = SortPrimary,
               SortSecondary = SortSecondary,
               mp = mp,
               MinWidth = MinWidth,
               Pad = Pad,
               IndivFigSize = IndivFigSize,
               BarSize = BarSize ,
               Orientation = Orientation,
               EdgeMode = EdgeMode,
               AxisLabels= c(PrimaryLab, SecondaryLab),
               FigureLabel = SiteNames,
               BoxLabPos = BoxLabPos,
               IncludePerc = IncludePerc ,
               PercentageDecimals = PercentageDecimals,
               PercPos = PercPos,
               CSS_Output_Supress = CSS_Output_Supress ,
               PRINT =  PRINT)
  
  LoadVisJS()
  
  # only line changed here to add d3_version = "5"
  r2d3::r2d3(data = NA, d3_version="5", script = paste0(filename,".js"),
             height= MainFigSize[2], width= MainFigSize[1] ,
             dependencies ="vizjs.js")
}

Used3v5(SmallTestWeb)
```

Comment: It's done! Thank you so very much! I did not put all the codes you provided; just installed the older version of r2d3 (0.2.3) and tried running the existing command lines. It is working perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: @SupratimLaha Glad to have helped - replacing the version of r2d3 is likely the simplest option of the three. Good luck in your presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded all the packages? The documentation suggests

```
library(r2d3)
library(bipartite)
library(purrr) 
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(bipartiteD3)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/bipartiteD3/vignettes/bipartiteD3_Intro.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have loaded all the packages even in the same order as it is given in the help file link.Also, I have up to date Java software in my PC. I am just stuck here!

Comment: Do other parts of bipartite work? such as `bipartite::plotweb(SmallTestWeb$meadow)` , perhaps the problem is simply with "demo1".

Comment: Yes, other parts are working fine. Only when the function bipartite_D3 is run, it shows that error message instead of graphical visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed older version of r2d3 (0.2.3) and it works perfectly showing the interactive bipartite graph in R viewer pane.
Here I am attaching the screenshot.
[Here is the screenshot of R studio showing the commands and graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6e5N.png)
Thank you @Andrew Reid